# Angular 8 with Material tabs - select last active tab on reload

Tags: angular, angular-router

Using the following example:

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dpxufm-iwpv3y?file=src/app/tab-group-basic-example.html)

How can I activate the last selected tab when a page is reloaded? Is there a design pattern of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a simple, naive hard-coded version:

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="1">
  <mat-tab label="system" routerLink="syspref"> Default Preferences </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="user" routerLink="userpref"> User Preferences </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

To make it more generic you would need to have some programmatic way of knowing how many tabs you have. For example, if you were building your tabs from an array.

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="tabs.length - 1">
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [label]="tab.label" [routerLink]="tab.link">{{tab.name}}</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Where tabs is an array of objects with appropriate property names.

Edit:

You want to persist the active tab across page reloads.

The general pattern that I follow for this is:

1. On tab change, add index to query params
2. On page load, find index in query params
3. If valid, set active tab index

**component**

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router) {}

selectedTabIndex: number;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.selectedTabIndex = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('tab'), 10);
  // TODO: check upper bound. Material will set the last tab as selected
  // if selectedTabIndex >= number of tabs
  if (isNaN(this.selectedTabIndex) || this.selectedTabIndex < 0) {
    this.selectedTabIndex = 0;
  }
}

onTabChange(selectedTabIndex: number): void {
  this.router.navigate([], { relativeTo: this.route, queryParams: {
    tab: selectedTabIndex
  }});
  this.selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex;
}
```

**html**

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selectedTabIndex" 
  (selectedIndexChange)="onTabChange($event)">
  <mat-tab label="system" routerLink="syspref"> Default Preferences </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="user" routerLink="userpref"> User Preferences </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough of what I was asking. By last I meant the last selected tab. The tab that was selected before a page was reloaded.

Comment: Ah, that is totally different :) I'll update my answer

Comment: I am looking into your code but want to ask this. I have a material toolbar and when I reload the page the last selected item on the toolbar gets navigated to and highlighted automatically. However, tabs get navigated properly, but not highlighted.

Comment: I don't actually know Material, so not sure of what else it expects. Can you update the stackblitz to demonstrate.

Comment: It is working but it shows this /settings/syspref?tab=0 in the address bar. Is that right?

Comment: What's the url of the page the tabs are on?

Comment: http://localhost:4200/settings. I am questioning ?tab=0 or any other tab index shown in the url.

Comment: After all that, it looks like Material has tab navigation built in: https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#tabs-and-navigation. So you shouldn't need to add tab to the query string because the active tab should be picked up from your route.

Comment: Not working. I replace my tabs with this: <mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      The First Content
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      The Second Content
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group> and the second tab is not selected automatically when it was selected before page reload.

Comment: Done. Use same example.

Comment: I couldn't get by amending your example, so set up a new stackblitz from scratch and copied your html across. It's now working with the query params method. You can navigate to a specific tab from another component using query params, or you can reload the tabs page. Each time the specified tab is selected based on the query string. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4nburn Is this what you were aiming for?

Comment: Yes, the results is what I want. However, I am not sure about additional parameters on urls. As I mentioned before similar functionality can be implemented without any custom code if I use mat-toolbar with routes. The last selected item is persisted when a page is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest storing the last tabIndex in localStorage.

Update the tabIndex to refer to the last saved index from localStorage.
So, when the page refreshes or goes back, it'll show the last shown tab.